# Gem installed rails 2.3.8, but not generate rdoc, how to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rdoc

I use `gem install rails -v=2.3.8` to install rails, and it says rdoc and ri has been generated.

But when I `gem server`, I can't open the rails doc in browser, it says `doc_root/rails-2.3.8/rdoc/index.html not found`

I looked into `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rails-2.3.8/rdoc`, found it is empty.

How to fix it? How to generate the rdoc by gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe re-generating might help: sudo gem rdoc --all

Comment: I deleted the empty `rails2.3.8` dir, and execute `gem rdoc --all`, but only generated empty `rails2.3.8` dir again

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this DIR "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/rails-2.3.5/"

Comment: @dilipchouhan, there is no rails 2.3.5, only 2.3.8